# Locally installed VIM Syntax not loading

Tags: vim, path

Whenever I load VIM 7.0 on my machine I understand that the program loads a lot of things from the path `/usr/share/vim/vim70/`. Now I have install locally (in the path `./vim74/src/vim`) the new version of VIM because I am not a sudo user. The problem I have is that it looks like program is searching for files in a directory that does not exist i.e. `/usr/local/share/vim/`. I cannot create such a directory so I wondered how could I set vim to look in the correct directory?

For reference I get error messages like

```
Error detected while processing /home/hep/flr09/.vimrc:
line   51:
E484: Can't open file /usr/local/share/vim/syntax/syntax.vim
Warning: Cannot find word list "en.utf-8.spl" or "en.ascii.spl"
line  292:
E484: Can't open file /usr/local/share/vim/syntax/syntax.vim
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

or like

```
Warning: Cannot find word list "en.utf-8.spl" or "en.ascii.spl"
Error detected while processing /home/hep/flr09/.vimrc:
line  292:
E484: Can't open file /usr/local/share/vim/syntax/syntax.vim
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following command installs Vim in `/home/username/foo/` as well as all its support files:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/home/username/foo && make && make install
```

It will create the following subdirectories and running that custom Vim will never source files from anywhere outside of `/home/username/`:

```
/home/username/foo/bin/
/home/username/foo/share/
…
```

Comment: I uninstalled the vim installed with my technique and started from scratch with yours and it worked perfectly.